# Why does this navbar not rescale?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want my navbar to be mobile friendly but it currently doesnt rescale autmatically, although I am using navbar-collapse.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top navbar-collapse collapse">      
   <!-- Top Bar -->
   <div class="navbar-inner">
      <a class="brand" href="#"></a>
      <ul class="nav navbar-left">
         <li><a href="">Return Home</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav pull-right">
         <li><p class="navbar-text navbar-right" style="color:#ffffff">{{viewer_name}}</p></li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</div>
</div>
```

How can I make the navbar to rescale automatically with the screen size?

Comment: Post your whole code with the CSS you have to make it rescale

Comment: this is bootstrap, it should be automatically responsive. You're doing something wrong on the css, try to make a live example with the error.